# Sending Mails From Local PC

Tags: email, smtp

I have a shared web hosting account and I have a forum with 35000 members. I want to mail them but the problem is that the server that's hosting my site is blocked by hotmail and the number is huge that no free SMTP service can get the job done.

So the question is, can I send emails from my computer, Windows or Linux? What do I need to do it if it's possible?

Comment: Mohannad? You can, but it's no guarantee that the emails will be accepted by the server.

Comment: Why is your site blocked by hotmail? It might be easier to troubleshoot THAT issue since it sounds like you already have an email service setup through that.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider taking a look at some of the remailer/relay services like http://www.changeip.com/. If the pricing meets your requirements, then it may also take the spam/blocking coordination efforts off your hands.